# In Groovy, why and how does assigning an ArrayList into a HashMap variable works?

Tags: groovy

I have the following code in Groovy that defies my logic:

```
HashMap<Integer,NLevelDynamicAlias> nLevelAliases = new ArrayList<>();
```

It was actually a typo. But the code works fine that I never realized it until I copied the code to a Java method.

How does Groovy allow that to work? Is that part of the supported coercion?

Answer (score 0):

groovy "magic" ))

try this code:

```
HashMap<Integer,String> nLevelAliases = [1,2,3];
```

and you'll get an error:

> > ... due to: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: 
> >         **Could not find matching constructor for: java.util.HashMap(java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Integer)**

means that groovy tries to find a constructor for type on the left with parameters specified in ArrayList on the right